# Issues starting Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm completely new to Android Studio which I've just downloaded. I've been trying to run a program using the emulator. Whenever I try this, I just get a phone which says Android on it, but nothing more. Each time, the log says the following:

```
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: device fd:684
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

I tried looking up how to handle this, and a solution seemed to be going to AVD Manager, editing the emulator and reducing the RAM in advanced settings. I tried reducing the RAM from 1512MB (or there abouts) to 1024MB, 512MB, 256MB and 128MB. None of these helped. Wondering if there are any other suggestions out there.

Thanks!

(My computer does have 4GB of RAM, incase that's useful info)

Comment: I recomend using a Virutal Machine with android x86 ;)

http://www.android-x86.org/

Comment: I think I am - I'm using the Nexus 5 API 23 x86 emulator / virtual device

Comment: You are using the emulator from the android sdk...
But you also can install a fresh android into a virtual machine (VMWare). You can find the image at http://www.android-x86.org/
Then you can connect the vm to adb with "adb connect *IP*"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [GennyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/). It is way better and much more faster than standart emulator.